# In Power BI how can I plot values of 2 or more columns on a line graph

Tags: powerbi

I have some timeseries data i.e value of voltage for every minute. It is stored in a database. I can plot this value using a Line chart. But now I have values from another table which is the allowed ranges of this voltage(I have this per min too..this is a sql view and I can change it to suit my needs.) I need to plot a graph with the actual value and the range data...so it would be 3 lines...2 constant(showing the max and min) and the actual value in the middle...In the Line graph, I cannot pull in multiple columns and plot the line. Is there any other visualization available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to plot several series on the same line chart. They way I do it is by first putting the multiple series on the same table.
Your new table would have three columns:

- Date, that you would assign to "Axis" in your line chart.
- Series, that contains a description of the line (e.g. voltage, min and max) and you would assign to "Legend".
- Value, that contains the actual value for each series and you assign to "Values" on the visual.

You can create this new table by doing a union query between your two original tables and adding the "Series" column to describe the Voltage the min and the max data.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou for this workaround..but the only problem is my data is too huge and the union is making the report take too long to execute.

Comment: Are you doing the union on Power BI or on the database? I would suggest doing the union of the database and power bi to read the resulting table right away. Other suggestion would be to use DirectQuery in the type of connection. My datasets are typically one million rows and this works fast with DirectQuery.